# Installing plugins and themes on Wordpress by web browser GUI

Tags: wordpress, ftp, xampp

I have installed XAMPP stack on the bitnami website. It bundles MySQL Database, ProFTPD, and Apache Web Server.

I cannot install plugins or themes from the web browser on wp-admin url. When I click install for a plugin I am directed to the page I need to enter ftp credentials.
First I have entered my username and password for the os x account I am using. It did not work. I have also tried with the username and password on the entrance page to the wordpress admin panel. It did not work also.

There are various solutions written on this site and different sites and on SO. But none of them solves this problem for me. It is possible to manually putting install folders into the related folders in the wordpress.

What is the problem with that?

It seems there is something to be fixed by the installer of this stack itself.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress only prompts for FTP credentials when the web server process does not have the essential file and folder permissions. You're need to make sure that your folders are using 750, or 755 and your files 644 or 640.

> [SOURCE](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)
>
> - All directories should be 755 or 750.
> - All files should be 644 or 640.

If your folders and files are set correctly then its likely because your files and folders have been uploaded using root or a personal account that the web server process has insufficient rights to the user group, this is refer to as ownership.

You need to ensure that the web server process has sufficient to read or write to these files/folders, to do so you can change ownership of the folder/files (recursively) using [chown](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/chown.1.html) or you could add the web server process (often `www-data`) to the [same user group](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-add-user-to-group-www-data/) as your personal account, but not root.

Comment: Is that the httpd process?

Comment: Varies from linux to linux, so yes it can httpd, hence why I said `often www-data`

Comment: thanks. once I was using xampp on mac os x. But now I have switched to the mamp and it offers to select install directory. I have Installed in a dir under my home. And no permissions, ownership issues I have seen so far.